# Signal Sigabrt when performing segue with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, xcode-storyboard

I am making an app using Swift and Xcode. I recently received a Signal Sigabrt when performing a segue. Here is the error:

```
2015-12-24 20:53:10.748 Passroom[8174:378664] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Passroom.DashboardViewController: 0x7f8043c55d40>) has no segue with identifier 'dashboard''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109eebf45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bd8cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   UIKit                               0x000000010aa1a9ea -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
3   **MYAPPNAME**                            0x00000001094891ce _TFC8Passroom14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 814
4   **MYAPPNAME**                            0x00000001094892b1 _TToFC8Passroom14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 49
5   UIKit                               0x000000010aa1d675 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 830
6   UIKit                               0x000000010aa1dff8 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 262
7   UIKit                               0x000000010a9e889e -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 827
8   UIKit                               0x000000010abbd24f -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 42
9   UIKit                               0x000000010a9ebfd5 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183
10  UIKit                               0x000000010b27eb24 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 101
11  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e56b6 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252
12  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e53c6 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1598
13  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e7c08 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
14  UIKit                               0x000000010a90d9df -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 241
15  UIKit                               0x000000010a90dd8e -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ebfafa0 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8a249b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c88a2af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e4c2e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e0d8a9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e0ce08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d71aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x000000010a88530d UIApplicationMain + 171
24  **MYAPPNAME**                           0x000000010949481d main + 109
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c8d692d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Note: My App Name is just a substitute for my actual app name.
Here is my storyboard:

[image: Main.Storyboard]

I am using this code to perform the segue:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboard", sender: self)
```

How should I fix this error? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you performing segue from within the left view controller?

Comment: Two guesses: maybe an unwanted invisible character in the identifier line. (The error message looks like). Retype the line. Or `dashboard` is some reserved term, change it to something else

Comment: Neither of these works for me unfortunately. I can't seem to debug this. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Did you try with model segue??

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by model segue?

Comment: You can see in your project the link show as push... see the link between 2 viewcontroller... you can change it as model... try it now